# Gnome White Screen of Death on AMD Laptop using Ubuntu;

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, windows-subsystem-for-linux, amd-graphics

I have installed Gnome shell onto Ubuntu on my new laptop (AMD Ryzen 7730U with Radeon Graphics). I am using WSL2.

Upon inputting `/usr/bin/gnome-session --session=gnome` into the Ubuntu command line I am greeted with the white screen of death.

I ran `journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell` and this is the log:

```
Feb 29 12:46:16 LAPTOP-6V6KHCPU gnome-shell[423]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 42.9) as a Wayland display server
Feb 29 12:46:16 LAPTOP-6V6KHCPU gnome-shell[423]: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
Feb 29 12:46:16 LAPTOP-6V6KHCPU gnome-shell[423]: Failed to open gpu '/dev/dri/card0': No suitable mode setting backend>
Feb 29 12:46:16 LAPTOP-6V6KHCPU org.gnome.Shell.desktop[423]: Failed to setup: No GPUs found

-- Boot 6d3b14d8e9fd4a639431140796d325fe --
Feb 29 14:14:33 LAPTOP-6V6KHCPU gnome-shell[382]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 42.9) as a Wayland display server
Feb 29 14:14:33 LAPTOP-6V6KHCPU gnome-shell[382]: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
Feb 29 14:14:33 LAPTOP-6V6KHCPU gnome-shell[382]: Failed to open gpu '/dev/dri/card0': No suitable mode setting backend>
Feb 29 14:14:33 LAPTOP-6V6KHCPU org.gnome.Shell.desktop[382]: Failed to setup: No GPUs found
Feb 29 15:12:57 LAPTOP-6V6KHCPU gnome-shell[384]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 42.9) as a Wayland display server
Feb 29 15:12:57 LAPTOP-6V6KHCPU gnome-shell[384]: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
Feb 29 15:12:57 LAPTOP-6V6KHCPU gnome-shell[384]: Failed to open gpu '/dev/dri/card0': No suitable mode setting backend>
Feb 29 15:12:57 LAPTOP-6V6KHCPU org.gnome.Shell.desktop[384]: Failed to setup: No GPUs found

-- Boot 808ffab7ca6442b197b97e545247e583 --
Feb 29 16:37:30 LAPTOP-6V6KHCPU gnome-shell[395]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 42.9) as a Wayland display server
Feb 29 16:37:30 LAPTOP-6V6KHCPU gnome-shell[395]: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
Feb 29 16:37:30 LAPTOP-6V6KHCPU gnome-shell[395]: Failed to open gpu '/dev/dri/card0': No suitable mode setting backend>
Feb 29 16:37:30 LAPTOP-6V6KHCPU org.gnome.Shell.desktop[395]: Failed to setup: No GPUs found
```

I gather it's something related to the GPU, but I'm not sure how to fix it.